# Change css of child on parent's pseudo-element (::after/::before) hover with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-element

Here's a fiddle of what I've tried and what I want to do:

```css
#child {color:white;}
#parent::after{
  content:"This";
  color:black;
}
#parent::after:hover + #child{
  color:black; 
}
#parent::after:hover ~ #child{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
    <span>Change child color when you hover</span>
    <div id='child'>
        Color
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover the `::after` of the `#parent`, I want to change the color of `#child`.

Is this possible to do with pure CSS, or do I have to use js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointer-events` can help you here

```css
#child {
  color: white;
}

#parent *,
#parent{
  pointer-events: none; /* disable for parent and all childs */
}

#parent::after {
  content: "This";
  color: black;
  pointer-events: initial; /* keep it for the pseudo element */
}

#parent:hover #child { /* the pseudo element will trigger this hover */
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <span>Change child color when you hover</span>
  <div id='child'>
    Color
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that way... For child element you can't use + or ~ sign. It's used for siblings not child.

```css
#child {color:white;}
#parent::after{
  content:"This";
  color:black;
}
#parent:hover #child{
  color:red; 
}
#parent:hover::after{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
    <span>Change child color when you hover</span>
    <div id='child'>
        Color
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what I'm trying to achieve, I need the child to change when I hover over `::after`, not the parent.

Comment: You can't hover "::after".Then you need to mention tag for hover